# Problem adding information to Table Widget

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt

I'm trying to add to the Table Widget the information that I have on my SQLite table.

That's it my SQL table:
[image: table].

That my Table Widget:
[image: Table Widget]

The code of the method:

`if self.ui.btn_jugadores.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ui.pila_de_paginas.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.pg_jugadores)): self.mostrar_jugadores()`

```
def mostrar_jugadores(self):
    try:

        cursor = conectarse_bbdd_jugadores() 
        consulta = ''' SELECT * FROM jugadores''' 
        ejecucion = cursor.execute(consulta).fetchall() 

       
        if len(ejecucion) > 0:
            
            fila = 0

            for e in ejecucion:
                columna = 0
                for apartado in e:
                    celda = QTableWidgetItem(apartado)
                    self.ui.tabla_jgds.setItem(fila, columna, celda)
                    columna += 1
                    print(apartado)

                fila += 1

        else:
            QMessageBox.setText('No hay registros en la tabla de jugadores')
            QMessageBox.setIcon(QMessageBox.warning)
            QMessageBox.exec_()



    except Error as error:
        QMessageBox.setText('No se ha podido ejecutar la sentencia')
        QMessageBox.setIcon(QMessageBox.warning)
        QMessageBox.exec_()
```

And this is the result:
[image: result] when I executed it

I don't know why the numbers are not appearing in the table widget.

Comment: Your first snippet of code doesn't make any sense. Why are you trying to do an `if` statement against a signal connection?

Comment: Because what I want to do is that if I press the button of that page I want to update that table. Do you understand me ?

Comment: That's exactly the point: doing `if signal.connect(...):` is pointless, as it will always execute the block within the if statement: what you're doing there is checking the return value of a function (`connect`). In this case, it would be the same as `if True: ...`. If you want to call `mostrar_jugadores` when clicking, then just create another connection: `self.ui.btn_jugadores.clicked.connect(self.mostrar_jugadores)`.

Comment: But the point what we are talking about it’s working, the problem is that the numbers don’t appear in the table. 
If the problem were in if , the table would be empty

Comment: You don't understand. I'm not referring to your actual problem, I'm saying that that `if` block is completely unnecessary (and conceptually wrong): you're **not** connecting the mouse click to `mostrar_jugadores`, and that function is not even called in that part of your code, as signal connections doesn't return a value considered positive for an if statement. That said, if your value is stored as integer in the database, you cannot use the constructor like that; you either use `QTableWidgetItem(str(apartado))` or add the value as DisplayRole using `celda.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, apartado)`.

Comment: Finally, for future reference, please try using function and variable names in English language: being able to read what an object is or does makes things much easier (especially for people that is going to help you). Consider that the majority of people on this website don't speak your language, and for them all your names are completely nonsense. This makes reading and understanding your code much more difficult and annoying, with the result that many people might even give up in trying to answer you, as they are not patient enough. Help us help you.

Comment: okey , thank you so much. Next time, i will write the functions in english, you are right. Sorry about that. After trying str(apartado) it´s  working perfectly. And i´m at the same point as the beginning, because .... i don´t understand why the if it´s wrong : (  Because if i code without the if i have to add another line as you said writting `self.ui.btn_jugadores.clicked.connect(self.mostrar_jugadores)`

Comment: `MostrarJugadores()` it´s only to make that the players in the databse appear in the table of the gui. But, i have a function call `conectarse_bbdd_jugadores()` that i use to connect to the database. Only for that. I´m not checking the return of that funcion when i use the if. I don´t know how to explain better sorry...

Comment: Any qt signal `connect` returns `None`, your `if self...connect(lambda: ...)` is the same as doing `if None: ...` (I inverted that part before, sorry). And, even in the case it worked, the problem remains. You want to call that function upon clicking, and your code does *not* do that. "I have to add another line": tell me what problem should represent adding a single line, especially if it works (as opposed to yours, which is incorrect and pointless)?